# Getting error converting dart2js on polymer project

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

> Unsupported operation: Can't use ownerName in reflection because it is not included in a @MirrorsUsed annotation.

`ownerName` is just an published attribute on the polymer element.  I understand there are a few things out there (on web, not on here) like this but none have a solid answer...

I also get this below it:

> NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol("title")'

Anyone got any ideas.  Been wrestling with this for 3 hours and ready to dump polymer.  Though It was fun in dartium, if it cannot convert to JS I see no real use in it.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:google_postendpoint_v1_api/postendpoint_v1_api_browser.dart';
import 'package:google_postendpoint_v1_api/postendpoint_v1_api_client.dart';
import 'dart:math';
//import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


/**
 * A Polymer post element.
 */
@CustomTag('post-element')
class SoberSky extends PolymerElement {
  @published int count = 0;
  @published String ownerName = "Casey";
  @published int ownerId = 888;
  @published int postId = 333;
  @published String content = "yo ho ho, and a bottle of rumsky!";
  @published String postContent = "This is an example of post content";

  @published int getOwnerId = 333;
  @published CollectionResponse_Comment listComment;
  @published CollectionResponse_Post listPost;
  @published String listCommentHTML;
  @published Post currentPost;
  @published bool yes = false;
  Postendpoint endpoint = new Postendpoint();
  var rng = new Random();

  var commentList;

  SoberSky.created() : super.created() {
    endpoint.rootUrl = "http://localhost:8888/"; // set the root URL
  }

  void getListComment([int tempPostId]) {
    if (tempPostId == null) {
      tempPostId = postId;
    }
    endpoint.listComment( tempPostId ).then((CollectionResponse_Comment commentCollection){
          this.listComment = commentCollection;
    }).catchError((e) => handleError(e));
  }

  void getPost() {
    endpoint.getPost( postId ).then((Post loadedMessage) {
      currentPost = loadedMessage; 
      getListComment(currentPost.key);
    }).catchError((e) => handleError(e));
  }

  void submitComment() {
    int id = rng.nextInt(1000);
    Comment comment = new Comment.fromJson({});
    comment.id = id;
    comment.content = content;
    comment.postId = postId;
    comment.ownerName = ownerName;
    comment.ownerId = ownerId;

    endpoint.insertComment( comment ).then((Comment savedComment) => endpoint.getComment(id)).
      then((Comment loadedMessage) {
        print(loadedMessage.content);
        getListComment(loadedMessage.postId);
      }).catchError((e) => handleError(e));  
  }

  void submitPost(){
    postId = rng.nextInt(1000);
    Post post = new Post.fromJson({});
    post.key = postId;
    post.ownerName = ownerName;
    post.ownerId = ownerId;
    post.title = postContent;

    endpoint.insertPost( post ).then((Post savedPost) => endpoint.getPost(postId)).
    then((Post loadedMessage) {
      print(loadedMessage.title);
      getPost();
      getListComment(loadedMessage.key);
    }).catchError((e) => handleError(e));
  }

  void handleError(Error e) {
    print("We had an error: ");
    print(e.toString());
  }

  @override
  void attached() {
  }
}
```

The HTML Polymer element

```html
<polymer-element name="click-counter" attributes="count">
  <template>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);" >
      <div class="entry">
        <label>Enter Post:</label>
        <input id="subject" type="text" value="{{postContent}}" size="45" maxlength="255">
        <button on-click="{{submitPost}}" class="btn btn-success" >Submit Post</button>    <br>

      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="post">  
      <h3>{{ currentPost.ownerName }}</h3>
      <p>{{ currentPost.title }}</p>
      <p>This is the postId: {{ currentPost.key }}</p>
  <p class="timestamp">{{ currentPost.uploadTime }}</p>
  <template repeat="{{comment in listComment.items}}">
    <div class="comment">
      <h3>{{ comment.ownerName }}</h3>
      <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
      <p>This is the commentId: {{ comment.id }}</p>
      <p class="timestamp">{{ comment.formatDate }}</p>
        </div>
      </template>
      <form action="javascript:void(0);">
        <label>Enter Comment:</label>
        <input id="subject" type="text" value="{{content}}" size="45" maxlength="255">
            <button on-click="{{submitComment}}" class="btn btn-success">Submit Comment</button>    <br>
      </form>  
     </div>  
   </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>  
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code of your polymer element

Comment: will do.  Didn't know if someone had immediately ran into this issue.  Seems like it is somewhat common but yet no definite solutions...

Comment: please add your HTML too.

Comment: Will get the polymer element up there!  Thanks

Comment: I just saw: If you override `enteredView()` you should call `super.enteredView()` otherwise you prevent proper insertion of your element into the DOM.

Comment: Hmmm... something had to have changed by removing that enteredView().  I wasn't using it anyways.  Now i get ->

Unsupported operation: This type does not support reflectedTypees 

Thanks for your help so far btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not yet seen your `Unsupported operation` message. Maybe some recent change. Your `NoSuchMethodError` is common when a property of a class is only referenced by a polymer expression (HTML) because tree-shaking drops all code that is not referenced and polymer expressions are not evaluated for this yet. The `@MirrorsUsed` annotation helps bridging this gap.

The problem is in your `Post` class because it's properties are only referenced in polymer expressions

```html
<div class="post">  
  <h3>{{ currentPost.ownerName }}</h3>
  <p>{{ currentPost.title }}</p>
  <p>This is the postId: {{ currentPost.key }}</p>
  <p class="timestamp">{{ currentPost.uploadTime }}</p>
```

To get your view updated when the properties in your `currentPost` change you should make your `Post` class like

```dart
class Post extends Object with Observable {
  @observable String ownerName;
  @observable String title;
  ...
}
```

If you have an annotation like `@reflectable`, `@published`, or `@observable` you don't need `@MirrorsUsed`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  Could you link to an example of how to use the @MirrorsUsed annotation.  Kind of new to this and just figuring everything out from the polymer tutorial.  Thanks

Comment: [MirrorsUsed class](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_mirrors/MirrorsUsed.html) has an example at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks Gunter for all the help.  I am going to try a few of these thigns you suggested and get this done tomorrow.  Late here and my brain is fried.

Comment: I do want to rant for a second and say that the fact that it works so beautifully in chromium and then gets destroyed in the transition to JS is disheartening...

Comment: This is a known problem the Dart team is working on.