# dart and observable attributes

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm writing a sample application with Polymer and Dart and I'm encountering an issue with observable attributes.

Here is the HTML code:

**clickcounter.html**

```html
<polymer-element name="click-counter">
  <template>
    <div>
      <button on-click="{{increment}}">Click me</button><br>
      <span>(click count: {{counter.count}})</span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**clickcounter.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @published Counter counter = new Counter();

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  }

  void increment() {
    counter.count++;
  }
}


class Counter {
  int count = 0;
}
```

When I click the increment button, the counter.count attribute is incremented but even if the counter attribute is observable, the new value is not reflected into the DOM !
I've read that the class must also be annotated with @observable or mixin with Observable, so I tried:

```html
@observable
class Counter {
  int count = 0;
}
```

and

```dart
class Counter with Observable {
  int count = 0;
}
```

but neither of these solutions work ! The only way to work is to annotate each attributes like this:

```dart
class Counter {
  @observable int count = 0;
}
```

I thought that annotate the class itself is the same as annotate all attributes. So anyone can explain me why it doesn't work and what is the proper way to make a class observable so any change will be reflect in the DOM?

**Env:**

> Polymer 0.9.3 / Polymer expressions 0.9.1 / Dart Editor version 1.0.0_r30798 (STABLE) / Dart SDK version 1.0.0.10_r30798

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: try: <template bind> in the template where you have counter.count

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting error converting dart2js on polymer project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855777/getting-error-converting-dart2js-on-polymer-project)

Comment: Paul can you give a link to <template bind> : I already saw this kind of code but until now I was unable to find an article which explains what it does ! Thks

Comment: it's mentioned here: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions plus more generically here. http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html It's probably nothing to do with it however but...

Answer (score 2):

You should change your model definition to the following:

```
class Counter extends Observable {
  @observable int count = 0;
}
```

`Counter` should extend `Observable` and the observed field should be annotated with `@observable`.

Comment: I seems to work without mixin Observable ! In Dartium and in JS